# How to read in a character array in C of indeterminate size?

Tags: c, arrays, file, io, character

I've tried both a recursive and iterative method to this, but I keep running into the issue of storing a character string of an indeterminate length. If their is some sort of library or Api call that reads until the next white space that would prove extremely helpful.

But essentially, I need to create an Array of Structs that contain character arrays.

Comment: C++ streams are a bit more intelligent (or stupid, depends on what you try). In C you need to use either gets (or fgets) or getc (or fgetc). What exactly are you struggling with? Can you provide code with your problem for us?

Comment: Consider `malloc()` and `realloc()` from standard C, or `getline()` or `getdelim()` from POSIX, or `stat()` and `mmap()` from POSIX.  Or use `getc()` and relatives, along with `malloc()` et al.  There are a legion ways to do it, in other words.

Comment: I perhaps wasn't clear enough. I'm storing raw text into a character array. But I don't know how many chars I'll be reading in until I hit a decimeter. I believe I have to use standard C. I'm a little confused how to use malloc() with this seeing as I don't already have something to determine the size of. I suppose I couldn't write my own dynamic array like behavior but I think that is beyond the scope of what I should be doing.

Comment: Yes, you need to use `malloc` for this. `malloc` needs the size of RAM you want to allocate and it returns a `void *`. You can cast this to any data type you want: `char *my_array = (char *)malloc( 10 );` The example allocates 10 bytes (chars) on heap. You can allocate a fixed amount of RAM, read until it is full andd allocate an array with a bigger size. Then copy your old array to the new one and free the old buffer. You can repeat this until you have the size you need. Do you need a more clear example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this example shows what you were looking for. I'd recommend to play around with `malloc` and `free` to discover it's behavior. Also read the comment at the goto, don't use `goto` unless you really know you are doing. You can fail very easy very hard using it. A `while` loop with a if to check if the buffer overflows with the next character would be better, but I was lazy so I left it as is. If you have any questions anymore please ask.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( ) {
  unsigned bufferSize = 0; // our array size
  int i = 0; // current position in buffer
  // we allocate memory for our buffer
  char *buffer = (char *)malloc( bufferSize += 10 );

  int ch = EOF; // set to eof, we will use this to buffer input

  // read input until buffer is full
repeat_input:
  for( ; i < bufferSize; i++ ) { // a while loop would be better for this job...
    ch = fgetc( stdin );
    if( ch == ' ' ) {
      // if there is a space we can break here
      goto done; // this is bad coding practice, i am just a bit lazy now
    }
    buffer[ i ] = ch;
  }

  // keep our old buffer pointer to not create a memleak
  char *old_buffer = buffer;
  buffer = (char *)malloc( bufferSize += 10 );

  // copy content of old buffer to new one
  int k = 0;
  for( k = 0; k <= i; k++ ) {
    buffer[ k ] = old_buffer[ k ];
  }

  // free RAM, else we have a memleak
  free( old_buffer );
  goto repeat_input;

done:
  fputs( buffer, stderr );
  free( buffer );
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Okay I'm starting to see what Is happening. But with malloc you still have to specify a finite space correct? Or does the += 10 allow it to dynamically grow beyond 10? I see your copying everything over from old_buffer to your newly defined buffer. Is this supposed to be handling the need for the buffer size to grow then?

Comment: @Aerlusch That is exactly what it does. Before `bufferSize` becomes passed as argument for the `malloc` call you increment it by 10. It's a bit of an abuse of the `+=` operator.

Comment: oh wow, I finally see. Very slick way of handling this. I also see that realloc is a possibility, I hadn't heard of that.

Comment: `realloc` might be an option, yes. I wanted to demonstrate the copy and free of the buffer. Just play with it and find the best way to do it.

Comment: Okay thank you a ton, this pretty much cleared up my confusions with file io and malloc/calloc in one fell swoop. I think that's it for now, unless I run into other troubles.

Answer (score 2):

use malloc and realloc for making space for your input.  Pick a reasonable starting size (you must have some sort of idea how many characters to expect).  Every time you realloc, double the size.

Comment: Okay, realloc looks like it could be the most graceful way of solving the reallocation part of this problem. I'm a little confused how to use it, since you pass it an existing block pointer, does that pointer now point to the new block? I'm reading the return type is void, but it also says it returns the pointer to your realloc'd block. Maybe the wording is off and it means implicitly returned or modified via the function.

Comment: Never mind. I miss read. The return type isn't void, but it is a pointer of *void. I understand realloc now.